# PLS-00905 - Error SQLPlus Oracle (PL/SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

Literal quiero preguntarle a todos ustedes que me puedan ayudar, que error ven en esta sentencia de PL/SQL

```
     create or replace procedure VER_TRIP_PAIS is
     cursor cur is
     SELECT a.bar_nombre,COUNT(b.trip_rut) total,c.pais_nombre
     into nombre_barco,cantidad_tripulantes,cantidad_tripulantes
     FROM Barco a, Tripulante b, Pais c
     WHERE a.bar_codigo=b.bar_codigo AND
     c.pais_codigo=b.pais_codigo
     BEGIN
     for i in cur loop
        dbms_output.put_line('Nombre Barco: '||i.bar_nombre)
        dbms_output.put_line('Pais: '|| i.pais_nombre)
        dbms_output.put_line('Cantidad de tripulantes: ' || i.total)
     end loop;
     end;

/
```

Agradecería un montón una respuesta.

Saludos

Comment: Los cursores no se definen así. Revisa la documentación. De paso, no nos preguntes qué error vemos, indica siempre qué estás intentando y qué debe salir como resultado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para empezar, te faltaría declarar i con ROWTYPE de cur ( i c1%ROWTYPE;)
También tendrías que cerrar todo con ;, y tendrías que lanzar antes de ejecutarlo un SET SERVEROUTPUT ON; .
Lo dejaría de la siguiente manera:

```
create or replace procedure VER_TRIP_PAIS is
     cursor cur is
     SELECT a.bar_nombre nombre_barco,COUNT(b.trip_rut) total,c.pais_nombre pais
     FROM Barco a, Tripulante b, Pais c
     WHERE a.bar_codigo=b.bar_codigo AND
     c.pais_codigo=b.pais_codigo;
     i cur%ROWTYPE;
     BEGIN
     for i in cur loop
        dbms_output.put_line('Nombre Barco: '||i.nombre_barco);
        dbms_output.put_line('Pais: '|| i.pais);
        dbms_output.put_line('Cantidad de tripulantes: ' || i.total);
     end loop;
     end;
/
```

Claramente, ejecutando anteriormente un SET SERVEROUTPUT ON; ya que sino el servidor no te mostrará nada con la orden dbms_output.put_line

Un saludo